# autofs fails to mount nfs mounts on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, upstart, autofs

When booting, the system fails to mount nfs mounts due to statd not being started. After manually starting statd, nfs mounts are automatically mounted by autofs.

Even though /etc/init/statd.conf specifies "mounting TYPE=nfs" in the "start on" line, this doesn't seem to work.

How does one solve this, other than manually starting statd after every boot?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the work-around I'm using, is to add an extra event (starting autofs) on the "start on" line in /etc/init/statd.conf:

```
start on (started portmap or mounting TYPE=nfs or starting autofs)
```

This makes upstart start statd before autofs is started.